# SaveChanges works on single CRUD operation but not mixed ones

Tags: c#, entity-framework, savechanges

I'm new to Entity framework and I have a stupid problem!

I fill a datagrid view with data then make changes and finally push a button to save changes.
As far as I just apply the same operation e.g as far as I just **Add** new records, there is no problem with saving data to db. But when I mix operations e.g when I **add** a new record **and** consecutively **delete** another one then push save button, changes are lost and neither operations are done on db.

On the button click event I Just have `ctx.SaveChanges()`; on try catch block!
What's wrong?
Does Entity framework have something like session or something which changes on each operation?

### Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace HiClinic
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        HiClinicEntities ctx = new HiClinicEntities();
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
            bs.DataSource = (from r in ctx.People select r).ToList();
            bs.AddingNew += new AddingNewEventHandler(personBindingSource_AddingNew);
            bs.AllowNew = true;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
        }
        void personBindingSource_AddingNew(object sender, AddingNewEventArgs e)
        {
            var p = new Person();
            ctx.People.Add(p);
            e.NewObject = p;
        }
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", ex);
            }
        }

        private void dataGridView1_UserDeletingRow(object sender,DataGridViewRowCancelEventArgs e)
        {
            var p = long.Parse(e.Row.Cells["PersonID"].FormattedValue.ToString());
            ctx.People.Remove(ctx.People.First<Person>(c=>c.PersonID == p));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code into the question?

Comment: for delete you need to call DeleteObject() first.

Comment: If you are using POCO objects, that don't have information abour the state of the entity, you need add to the context the entity in the correct state, so if you only add the entities to the context and save changes, entity frame work will don't know what to do with each entity.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Any exceptions?

Comment: no errors no exceptions. It works perfectly if I just add rows and save or delete and save but when I mix add and delete nothing happens on DB

Comment: It seems as if I work directly with DB it works i.e.
`private void dataGridView1_UserDeletingRow(object sender, DataGridViewRowCancelEventArgs e)
{
var pid = long.Parse(e.Row.Cells["PersonID"].FormattedValue.ToString());
            try
            {
                var p = ctx.People.First<Person>(c => c.PersonID == pid);
                ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("delete from person where personid=" + p.PersonID.ToString());
            }
            catch 
            {
            }
}`